# Flutter widget using generate to generate values

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter widget I am working on, and I want the options to be 0-99 by .25 increments.  I'm pretty sure you use the generate function, but I can't figure out how to get it in the particular format I am using.  What data type is it? etc.  Can someone please take a look?

```
Widget _Display(display) {
  if (display == true){
    return Expanded(
    child: ChoicesWidget(
    Options: [
      {
        "display": "1",   //these are the values I want to go from 0-99 by increments of .25.
        "value": 1,
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "display": "1.25",
        "value": 1.25,
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  ),);
  }
  else return Container();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a while loop and gen something for you:

```
Widget _Display(display) {
    var min = 0.0;
    var max = 99.0;
    var current = min;

    List<Map<String, Object>> options = [];
    while (current <= max) {
      options.add(
        {
          "display": current.toString(),
          "value": current,
          "checked": false,
        },
      );
      current += 0.25;
    }

    if (display == true) {
      return Expanded(
        child: ChoicesWidget(Options: options),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That should do it.  Thanks!